# Config section in shopify

Tags: shopify

i having a problem Shopify .
I need to create config sections between sections for admin.
I just learned about the file settings_schema.json. 
everyone please help me. Thanks

Comment: Hi Tony!  Can you please elaborate a little on what you're after? Are you looking to create theme customizations and just need help with the syntax?  Are you trying to use the Sections folder to create content with its own settings?  There are a lot of different things in Shopify that can have config settings - if you can be more specific I'm sure we can help you out. :)

Comment: Hi Dave B.
i want config distance between section.
i have a lot of section in content
Now I want to configure the admin to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for the "header" type of setting entry - see https://help.shopify.com/en/themes/development/theme-editor/settings-schema#sidebar-settings

By adding headers between groups of settings, Shopify will give a bit of extra visual space between them.